# VK API - Примитив JSON unread 42 c#

Tags: c#

У меня вот такая проблема:

У меня messages.get берет диалоги , а теперь устарела , а мне нужно теперь перевести  метод на messages.getConversations.

```
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string text = StrWrk.qSubstr(VKserver.APIRequest("messages.get", "count=100", this.token, ""), "\"items\":", false);
                string input = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2);
                this.msgs = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Message>>(input);
```

Вот такой код, а когда просто меняю с messages.get на messages.getConversations, то выдает ошибку примитив JSON unread 42, помогите.

Comment: В таких случаях прибегают к отладке. Выдергивают вызов этого метода `VKserver.APIRequest()` из матрешки в локальную переменную. Ставят на эту строку точку останова, запускают в режиме дебагинга, делают шаг вперед, смотрят значение получившейся переменной, прикидывают что не так, исправляют...